# How to create /dev/null on BSD?

Tags: freebsd, devices

A wrongly written script deleted `/dev/null` on my system. I did find an answer [here](/questions/27279) and tried it out. But as soon as I write something to the new `/dev/null`, the system crashes. I'm afraid that answer's not for BSD.

Can anyone help?

It's FreeBSD 10.3

Comment: What did you try? Using `mknod` or `MAKEDEV`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On FreeBSD:

```
mknod /dev/null c 15 0 root:wheel
chmod 0666 /dev/null
```

As you found out, numbers 15 and 0 are not portable to other systems.

Comment: Is this portable to all BSD-based systems?

Comment: @iBug Nope.  OpenBSD f.i. needs 2 and 2.

Answer (score 6):

The command for creating device node entries is [`mknod`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mknod&sektion=8) on pretty much all unix systems. The device numbers are completely depend on the unix variant, so you need to look them up in the documentation. On some systems, `man 4 null` (the `null` man page in section 4 “special files”) will tell you what the device numbers are. (Devices are in section 4 on BSD and Linux, but the section number can vary on other Unix variants, for example it's section 7 on Solaris.)

If the man pages don't tell you, look for a [`MAKEDEV`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=MAKEDEV&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+4.0-RELEASE) command, usually located in `/dev`. This is usually a shell script where you can easily find out the device number, or run it as `cd /dev && ./MAKEDEV null`.

Some modern unix systems don't use `MAKEDEV` because device nodes are created automatically. This is the case on Linux systems (except some embedded systems) with udev, and also on FreeBSD with [devfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.0-RELEASE). How to re-create an entry that's normally created automatically depends on the automatic device creation system. On FreeBSD, you can simply give the device name to the `mknod` command: `mknod /dev/null`.